# Keep getting NSMultipleValuesMarker <MULTIPLE VALUES MARKER> on arrayController valueForKeyPath:

Tags: cocoa, binding, cocoa-bindings

This code works fine for single selections or multiple selections in the table with the same values for the selected objects.

```
NSNumber *currentValue = (NSNumber *)[mArrayController valueForKeyPath: mBindingKeyPath];
```

But if I have multiple selections with different values for the selected objects, I get this error and crash – which is correct because I do have multiple selections in my table.
But of course I don't want to crash and instead get the selection as an array or how is it supposed to work?

```
2014-04-24 17:20:33.167 DC MacOSX[5746:303] -[_NSStateMarker floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006135a0
2014-04-24 17:20:33.168 DC MacOSX[5746:303] -[_NSStateMarker floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006135a0
2014-04-24 17:20:33.170 DC MacOSX[5746:303] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b71bb06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff850b03f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b7b240a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b70a02e ___forwarding___ + 414
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b709e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5   Dreamcatcher MacOSX                 0x0000000100066199 -[CustomNSSliderJoystick1D mouseDragged:] + 434
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff89a60b81 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 8504

7   AppKit                              0x00007fff89a5c644 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google:
"NSArrayController class reference"

Find: `selectedObjects:`

The `NSArrayController` instance methods are what you're going to want to use to query the selection. The binding guarantees that the array controller is in a *state* that matches whatever you have bound it to, usually a view. But the whole point of binding it, is so that you can use `NSArrayController` methods to access that state.

This answer seems flippant -- let me google that for you -- but you're new, and *especially* with OSX APIs, you'll be referring to developer.apple.com class references all the time. AppKiDo and Dash are great tools to do that with.

You will also find `isKindOfClass` useful.

Comment: Hah! I see now how obvious the answer to my question was – I went blind but now my eyes are open again :-) Thx for your time & effort!